# Not able to retrieve mentions in Twit twitter node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter

Trying to make a twitterbot using twit NPM. Am able to tweet from the bot but not able to stream or retrieve mentions.

Here is the code:

```
var restclient = require('node-restclient');
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         '[KEY]', 
  consumer_secret: '[SECRET]',
  access_token:         '[TOKEN]',
  access_token_secret:  '[TOKEN-SECRET]'
}); 

T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'Hello World! #firstTweet' }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data);
})  // Working

T.get('statuses/mentions_timeline.json' , {count: 10}, function (data) {
  console.log(data);
}); // Not working

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '@thefoodbot', language: 'en' })
  stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet);
  }) // Not working
```

Getting the following error when trying to retrieve mentions:

```
{ statusCode: 404, data: '{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}', twitterReply: '{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}' }
```

And stream doesn't respond at all.

Comment: Does this help? 'Intermittent 404 responses from REST API' https://twittercommunity.com/t/intermittent-404-responses-from-rest-api/46712 - it's this year at least!

Comment: @PhilCooper Still nothing.